# Word for "complementing each other, while showing an increase in intensity"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, adverbs

I have 2 sentences. The sentences are:

> In college, I wrote a simple calendar program. **Concurrently**, 2 years on, I am working on developing a complex universal calendar system.

Here, I want "concurrently" to be replaced with an appropriate word. If the 2 sentences were opposite of each other, I would have used "conversely". But in this case, the 2 sentences complement each other while showing an increase in intensity.

Comment: Maybe simply _since then_. Or _moreover_ if it's part of an argument for something.

Comment: Not exactly one word, but would "following that" work?

Comment: I assume you are at least somewhat finished with your first calendar program. If I'm correct, then how can you still be working on it at the same time you're working on the new, complex system. I'm confused. "Concurrent" would mean you're working on both programs at the same time. Why not simply start the next sentence with, "Two years on, I am working . . ."? Or, if you want to provide a contrast between the two programs, you could say, "Building on the success of my first program, I am now designing a complex universal calendar system." The words "simple" & "complex" provide u with contrast.

Comment: @rhetorician Sorry for not giving more details. I actually am writing my statement of purpose and I didn't write the exact sentence as I didn't want it to be flagged when the universities check my essay for plagiarism. The actual sentence goes something like this "Sitting in my dorm, I was configuring QuickBooks, an ERP software. This was my first interaction with IT. Concurrently, 2 years on, I am customizing a highly complex SAP ERP system.
I guess I can use subsequently here instead of concurrently. I just wanted to show my growth in knowledge. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that "concurrently" is not the right word. How about **"successively"**?

"Full Definition of successive
1
:  following in order :  following each other without interruption 
2
:  characterized by or produced in succession"

See: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/successively

Answer (score 2):

Consider **subsequently**.

> Definition: occurring or coming later or after something else.
>
> Example: *Mary made a word tour when she was 45. She subsequently devoted her life to writing*.

Comment: This seems like a good option.
I will write it as "I was doing A in college. Subsequently, now I am doing B".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a suitable adverb that can show an **increase in intensity in your context**. And your first sentence reads a little awkward. It is better not to use "in college" and replace it with "when I was a (college) freshman". Then, you could use **accumulated knowledge and skill (or experience)** in the sentence as follows:

> **When I was a (college) freshman**, I wrote a simple calendar program. But **with accumulated knowledge and skill for two (or X) years**, I am working on developing a complex universal calendar system.

The two sentences are showing **contrast** as it is (as commented by Rhetorician). You can show **increase in intensity** by using *accumulated knowledge and skill* as you gain them as your experience is accumulated over a certain period time.

Comment: Sorry for not giving more details. I actually am writing my statement of purpose and I didn't write the exact sentence as I didn't want it to be flagged when the universities check my essay for plagiarism.
The actual sentence goes something like this "Sitting in my dorm, I was configuring QuickBooks, an ERP software. This was my first interaction with IT. concurrently, 2 years on, I am customizing a highly complex SAP ERP system.

Comment: @manoj You are using the adverb *concurrently* wrongly. That's it. I am done.

Comment: Yeah, I will change concurrently to subsequently. I just needed a work connecting both the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the word "now" or "today"...

In college, I wrote a simple calendar program. Today, 2 years on, I am working on developing a complex universal calendar system.